# Kynetx and SOAP

Tags: soap, krl

I have been searching the web and Kynetx.com for any documetation or examples of how to use SOAP with KRL but have come up with nothing. Sadly the web services I am working with has a lot of SOAP rather then REST. If there is any links of documentation or examples of doing SOAP with KRL I would be really pleased if you would pass that on to me, i'm not even sure where to start, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no SOAP support in KRL. The best way to get these APIs into KRL is to create a REST-SOAP shim that translates between the two.

Comment: Thanks good to know. And by shim do you mean set up end points on a server that when called will make a SOAP call on that server and then get the return output and return a Json format object of that output? Like an intermediary.

Comment: After talking with sam yesterday it would seem that is exactly what a shim is, an intermediary.